# MySQL: Selecting from multiple tables that have no relationship

Tags: php, mysql, join

First post, be gentle!  My SQL knowledge is average, at best.

I have 2 tables with no direct relationship to each other.

- TableA ("CustomerWishList") with columns "bookID", other-book-data,
  etc etc etc
- TableB ("CustomerOwned") with columns - "bookID", other-book-data, etc etc etc

A book could be in one, both, or none of those tables.

I need to create SQL statement that counts the number of `"bookID='data'"` occurrences in either TableA or TableB.

So far using PHP I'm searching TableA `"bookID"` column first, and then if nothing found, searching TableB `"bookID"` column next ... it works, but is inefficient, and am convinced there must be a better way.

JOIN statements don't seem to apply here? - I could be wrong.

---

**UPDATED**

Psuedo PHP code I'm currently using:

```
$total=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CustomerWishList WHERE BOOKID=1234

if ($total==0) {
    $total2=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CustomerOwned WHERE BOOKID=1234
}  
return $total2;
```

Comment: Posting the PHP code that you mentioned here may help.

Comment: The common bookID is a relationship. Since you didn't show what you've tried all we can really do is give you some suggestions: You can achieve what you want with COUNT IF or CASE - study both of them.

Comment: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Since we dont have full information we cant be sure of how everything is setup. Just wanted to give a friendly advise. If it is like i think that you could have a book in both tables with all data being the same, it might be a better idea to have a single table with all the books and their data. And then have another table called CustomerWishList that just holds the UserID and the bookID and another table called CustomerOwned. Then you dont need to have multiple copies of all information. Might not be the case here but just a tip if it is like that. Good luck.

Comment: Feedback appreciated - I've added some pseudo code above

Answer (score 0):

Below query would give you count of book ids which are only in table A:

```
SELECT count(1) as `count`
FROM tableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT bookID FROM tableB WHERE bookID = tableA.bookID);
```

Similarly, following query would give you count of book ids which are only in table B:

```
SELECT count(1) as `count`
FROM tableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT bookID FROM tableA WHERE bookID = tableB.bookID);
```

Now, if you want to `add` these two then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT `a.count` + `b.count`
FROM ( 
 SELECT count(1) as `count`
 FROM tableA
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT bookID FROM tableB WHERE bookID = tableA.bookID)
 ) a,
(
 SELECT count(1) as `count`
 FROM tableB
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT bookID FROM tableA WHERE bookID = tableB.bookID);
) b;
```